# TypeScript inference doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference

Let's imagine we have the following definitions, I don't understand why TypeScript still doesn't infer the types correctly!

Anyone knows how to write it correctly?

Notes:
* Make sure you turn on "Strict Null Check" option.
* I commented the code to explain the issue, if it's not clear please comment.

```
type Diff<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
type NotNullable<T> = Diff<T, null | undefined>; 
type OptionType<T> = T extends NotNullable<T> ? 'some' : 'none';
interface OptionValue<T> {
  option: OptionType<T>;
  value: T;
}

let someType: OptionType<string>; // evaludates to 'some' correctly
let noneType: OptionType<undefined>; // evaluates to 'none' correctly
let optionSomeValue = { option: 'some', value: 'okay' } as OptionValue<string>; // evaluates correctly
let optionNoneValue = { option: 'none', value: null } as OptionValue<null>; // evaluates correctly

let getValue = <T>(value: T): (T extends NotNullable<T> ? OptionValue<T> : OptionValue<never>) =>
  ({ option: value ? 'some' as 'some' : 'none' as 'none', value });

let handleSomeValue = <T>(obj: OptionValue<T>) => {
  switch (obj.option) {
    case 'some':
      return obj.value;
    default:
      return 'empty' as 'empty';
  }
}

let someStringValue = 'check'; // type string
let someNumberValue = 22;
let someUndefinedValue: string | null | undefined = undefined;

let result1 = handleSomeValue(getValue(someStringValue)); // it is 'string' correctly
let result2 = handleSomeValue(getValue(someNumberValue)); // should be 'number' but it's 'number | empty'
let result3 = handleSomeValue(getValue(someUndefinedValue)); // it is 'empty' correctly;
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Diff%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20U%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20T%3B%0D%0Atype%20NotNullable%3CT%3E%20%3D%20Diff%3CT%2C%20null%20%7C%20undefined%3E%3B%20%0D%0Atype%20OptionType%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20NotNullable%3CT%3E%20%3F%20'some'%20%3A%20'none'%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20OptionValue%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20option%3A%20OptionType%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20someType%3A%20OptionType%3Cstring%3E%3B%20%2F%2F%20evaludates%20to%20'some'%20correctly%0D%0Alet%20noneType%3A%20OptionType%3Cundefined%3E%3B%20%2F%2F%20evaluates%20to%20'none'%20correctly%0D%0Alet%20optionSomeValue%20%3D%20%7B%20option%3A%20'some'%2C%20value%3A%20'okay'%20%7D%20as%20OptionValue%3Cstring%3E%3B%20%2F%2F%20evaluates%20correctly%0D%0Alet%20optionNoneValue%20%3D%20%7B%20option%3A%20'none'%2C%20value%3A%20null%20%7D%20as%20OptionValue%3Cnull%3E%3B%20%2F%2F%20evaluates%20correctly%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20getValue%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(value%3A%20T)%3A%20(T%20extends%20NotNullable%3CT%3E%20%3F%20OptionValue%3CT%3E%20%3A%20OptionValue%3Cnever%3E)%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20(%7B%20option%3A%20value%20%3F%20'some'%20as%20'some'%20%3A%20'none'%20as%20'none'%2C%20value%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20handleSomeValue%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(obj%3A%20OptionValue%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20switch%20(obj.option)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20'some'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20obj.value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20default%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20'empty'%20as%20'empty'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20someStringValue%20%3D%20'check'%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20string%0D%0Alet%20someNumberValue%20%3D%2022%3B%0D%0Alet%20someUndefinedValue%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%20%7C%20undefined%20%3D%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20result1%20%3D%20handleSomeValue(getValue(someStringValue))%3B%20%2F%2F%20it%20is%20'string'%20correctly%0D%0Alet%20result2%20%3D%20handleSomeValue(getValue(someNumberValue))%3B%20%2F%2F%20should%20be%20'number'%20but%20it's%20'number%20%7C%20empty'%0D%0Alet%20result3%20%3D%20handleSomeValue(getValue(someUndefinedValue))%3B%20%2F%2F%20it%20is%20'empty'%20correctly%3B%0D%0A) link

Comment: `someValue` has an implicit type of `any`. Wouldn't you then expect `getValue(someValue)` to return an `OptionValue<any>`?

Comment: No sure it should work that way according to these docs: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html

Comment: The return type of `getValue` is `OptionValue<T>`, and at the call site, `T` is inferred to be the type of the argument `someValue`, which is `string | undefined`.  Thus the instantiated return type is `OptionValue<string | undefined>`.  Why do you expect it to be `OptionValue<never>`?

Comment: You're right. It can't be `OptionValue<never>` but even that didn't help to get the result correctly.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I updated the question to follow your comment. Please check it out. Thanks.

Comment: I gotta admit, TypeScript doesn't work with sophisticated type inference very well :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to unpack here, but the short version is that you need to use explicit type annotations to get this to work, inference has it's limits.

It is interesting to look at why this apparently works as you expect it to in some of the cases.

Firstly the inferred signature of `handleSomeValue` is `<T>(obj: OptionValue<T>) => T | "empty"`. Notice there is no relation between `T` and whether `'empty'` is included in the return type or not, the result is always `T | "empty"`. So why is `'empty'` sometimes missing and `T` sometimes missing. Well that has to do with the rules of how unions are evaluated.

Lets consider the first example

```
let someStringValue = 'check'; // type string
let result1 = handleSomeValue(getValue(someStringValue));
```

here the `T` to `handleSomeValue` will be `string`, so the result will be `string | 'empty'` but `"empty"` is a subtype of `string` so string will eat up the literal type `"empty"` (because it's redundant) and the result will be `string`

Now let's look at the third example which also appears to work:

```
let someUndefinedValue: string | null | undefined = undefined;
let result3 = handleSomeValue(getValue(someUndefinedValue)); // it is 'empty' correctly;
```

While here `someUndefinedValue` appears to be typed as `string | null | undefined` it is in fact not, if you hover over `someUndefinedValue` in the second line you will see it is typed as `undefined`. This is because flow analysis determines that the actual type will be `undefined` because there is no path for the variable to be `undefined`.

This means that `getValue(someUndefinedValue)` will return `OptionValue<never>`, so the `T` in `handleSomeValue` will be `never` so we get `never | 'empty'`. And since `never` is a subtype of all types (see [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8652)) `never | 'empty'` will just evaluate to `'empty'`.

It's interesting to note that when `someUndefinedValue` is actually `string | undefined` the example fails to compile because `getValue` will return `'OptionValue<string> | OptionValue<never>'` and the compiler will not be able to infer `T` correctly.

```
let someUndefinedValue: string | null | undefined = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "" : undefined;    
let result3 = handleSomeValue<string | never>(getValue(someUndefinedValue)); // Argument of type 'OptionValue<string> | OptionValue<never>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OptionValue<string>'
```

With this understanding it becomes obvious why the second example does not work as expected.

```
let someNumberValue = 22;
let result2 = handleSomeValue(getValue(someNumberValue)); // should be 'number' but it's 'number | empty'
```

`getValue` returns `OptionValue<number>` so the `T` in `handleSomeValue` will be `number` and the result will thus be `number | 'empty'`. Since the two types in the union have no relation, the compiler will not try to simplify the union any further and will leave the result type as is.

### The solution

A solution that works as you expect and the preserves the `'empty'` literal type is not possible because the union of `string | 'empty'` will always be `string`. We can prevent the simplification if we use branded types to add something to `empty` to prevent the simplification. Also we will need an explicit type annotation for the return type that will correctly identify the return type:

```
type Diff<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
type NotNullable<T> = Diff<T, null | undefined>; 
type OptionType<T> = T extends NotNullable<T> ? 'some' : 'none';
interface OptionValue<T> {
    option: OptionType<T>;
    value: T;
}

let someType: OptionType<string>; // evaludates to 'some' correctly
let noneType: OptionType<undefined>; // evaluates to 'none' correctly
let optionSomeValue = { option: 'some', value: 'okay' } as OptionValue<string>; // evaluates correctly
let optionNoneValue = { option: 'none', value: null } as OptionValue<null>; // evaluates correctly

let getValue = <T>(value: T): (T extends NotNullable<T> ? OptionValue<T> : OptionValue<never>) =>
({ option: value ? 'some' as 'some' : 'none' as 'none', value }) as any;

type GetOptionValue<T extends OptionValue<any> | OptionValue<never>> = 
    T extends OptionValue<never> ? ('empty' & { isEmpty: true }) :
    T extends OptionValue<infer U> ? U: never ;

let handleSomeValue = <T extends OptionValue<any> | OptionValue<never>>(obj: T) : GetOptionValue<T>=> {
switch (obj.option) {
    case 'some':
    return obj.value;
    default:
    return 'empty' as  GetOptionValue<T>;
}
}
let someStringValue = 'check'; // type string
let result1 = handleSomeValue(getValue(someStringValue)); // it is 'string' correctly
let someNumberValue = 22;
let result2 = handleSomeValue(getValue(someNumberValue)); //is number


let someStringOrUndefinedValue: string | null | undefined = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "" : undefined;    
let result3 = handleSomeValue(getValue(someStringOrUndefinedValue)); // is string | ("empty" & {isEmpty: true;})

let someUndefinedValue: undefined = undefined;    
let result4 = handleSomeValue(getValue(someUndefinedValue)); // is "empty" & { isEmpty: true; }
```

Comment: First of all I appreciate you taking the time and answering the question.

Based on your explanation TypeScript compiler only differs if two complete interface/structure do NOT have any common patterns should be able to infer the types properly.

Comment: ...
IMHO Your solution adds up more complexity to my example. The whole reason I was using option in the interface was to let the compiler have a clue about the structure that has a value or not and to be able to differentiate and therefor infer.
To me you adding isEmpty as a boolean is the same as option being 'some' or 'none'. Now my question to you is, is it possible to simplify this problem or this can't be solve due to limitation of the language?

Comment: @AminPaks The reason for `isEmpty` is that you want to use a string value to have a special meaning. If `T` is `string` there is a problem there, the compiler will rightly think that `string | 'empty'` is just `string` why shouldn't it be ? We can let the compiler know it should not be so if we make the string `'empty'` different from other string, ie we make it special in some other way. You could use a dedicated `enum` instead, that would let the compiler know,

Comment: Would you update your answer with a solution based on your latest comment? Thanks

Comment: @AminPaks I just tried to do it with an enum and there are some other issues with how enums are widened. (the enum literal type is not preserved for some reason) here is gist of it if you want to play around with it : https://gist.github.com/dragomirtitian/696bcba440342aaa8fc964d1fcca5075

Comment: It’s quite interesting what you’ve done. Nonetheless I think this is a (strong) limitation of TypeScript compiler and I think maybe the core team might be able to solve/give directions better. Bottom line is the inference in TypeScript has a long way to go.

Comment: @AminPaks it's far from perfect, I'll agree with you on that :) File a bug on GitHub, see their feedback. ryan-cavanaugh hangs out around here at times, maybe he'll comment, but the best place to interact with the team is GitHub

Answer (score 0):

The inferred return type of `handleSomeValue` is computed as the union of the types of all of the returned expressions, i.e., `T | "empty"`.  At each call site, this return type is instantiated with the type argument for `T`.  TypeScript does not re-analyze the body of `handleSomeValue` for each call to see which cases of the switch are reachable depending on `T`.  If you wanted, you could annotate `handleSomeValue` like this:

```
type SomeValueReturn<T> = T extends NotNullable<T> ? T : "empty";
let handleSomeValue = <T>(obj: OptionValue<T>): SomeValueReturn<T> => {
  switch (obj.option) {
    case 'some':
      return obj.value as SomeValueReturn<T>;
    default:
      return 'empty' as SomeValueReturn<T>;
  }
}
```

But I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The whole point of type inference is to not give the type system this much details and let it work. So far we repeated ourselves too many times to reach to this point. I was trying to achieve a simple monad in TypeScript but gave up cause it’s just not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `T` is not NotNullable nor `Diff<T, U>`.  If you input type `T`, it will alway return the same.  You must instruct the compiler how to do

You must define new type that wrap `OptionValue<T>`:

```js
type OptionValue2<T> = OptionValue<NotNullable<T>>;

let getValue = <T>(value: T): OptionValue2<T> => ({
  option: value ? "some" : "none",
  value
});

let someValue: undefined;
let value = getValue(someValue); // this type will be OptionValue<never>

// still use OptionValue
let handleSomeValue = <T>(obj: OptionValue<T>): SomeValueReturn<T>  => {
  switch (obj.option) {
    case "some":
      return obj.value as T;
    default:
      return "empty" as "empty";
  }
};
```

```js
let someUndefinedValue: string | null | undefined = undefined;
```

For last case, Typescript compiler evaluate type only. It can not know if the result is string or null. You can not expect dynamic value evaluation